# Lerp vs tweening

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tween

I am trying to rotate an object (in one axis) according to user input (for example keyboards left/right arrows). I am using a `Rigidbody` with method `MoveRotation`.

So in `FixedUpdate`, I am creating frame-independent angular movement using `Mathf.Lerp`.

```
rotation = Mathf.Lerp(rotation, rotation + input, Time.deltaTime * speed)
```

But this is linear, and I want to smooth this rotation (for example `Sine.easeIn`), so it's starting to rotate slowly, and after awhile it's fully rotating.

What is the best way in Unity to combine tweening with user input and frame-independence. (I think I cannot use libraries like `DOTween` or `iTween` because the time of tween is not known.

Comment: Do you want to cap the rotation at some point or continue to accelerate? Also do you have to use tweening or would you consider the physics engine?

Comment: let's say I want to cap it at some point (also with `tweening`), but this tweenable cap isn't my main concern here. I want to use pure math (but knowing both solutions would be nice)

Comment: Did you check the answer I provided?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html) to accelerate the object around its axis.

```
Rigidbody.AddTorque(torqueVector3, ForceMode.Accelerate);
```

You will need to add a Rigidbody for this to work, the parameter ForceMode is set to accelerate which according to the Unity docs will:

> Add a continuous acceleration to the rigidbody, ignoring its mass.

You could add some code to cap the velocity I think, something like:

```
if (Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude >= capAmount)
{
    Rigidbody.velocity.magnitude = capAmount;
}
```

Another more global way to cap rotation would be to change the [max angular velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-maxAngularVelocity.html).

Comment: And what about using custom interpolation method, not Physics engine?

Answer (score 0):

> so it's starting to rotate slowly, and after awhile it's fully
>   rotating.

This can be done with a coroutine. Start a coroutine and do everything in a `while` loop. Have a variable that increments over time with `Time.deltaTime` when the left/right arrow key is pressed.

```
public Rigidbody objectToRotate;
IEnumerator startRotating()
{
    float startingSpeed = 10f;
    const float maxSpeed = 400; //The max Speeed of startingSpeed

    while (true)
    {
        while (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (startingSpeed < maxSpeed)
            {
                startingSpeed += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            Quaternion rotDir = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * -(Time.deltaTime * startingSpeed));
            objectToRotate.MoveRotation(objectToRotate.rotation * rotDir);
            Debug.Log("Moving Left");
            yield return null;
        }

        startingSpeed = 0;

        while (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if (startingSpeed < maxSpeed)
            {
                startingSpeed += Time.deltaTime;
            }
            Quaternion rotDir = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * (Time.deltaTime * startingSpeed));
            objectToRotate.MoveRotation(objectToRotate.rotation * rotDir);
            Debug.Log("Moving Right");
            yield return null;
        }
        startingSpeed = 0;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Just start the coroutine form the `Start()` function once. It should run forever. It will rotare slowly to fast until `maxSpeed` is reached.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(startRotating());
}
```

You can modify the `startingSpeed` and `maxSpeed` variable to suite your need. If you think that it is taking so long to reach the `maxSpeed`, you can always multiply `startingSpeed` with another number after adding `Time.deltaTime;` to it. For example, change `startingSpeed += Time.deltaTime;` to `startingSpeed += Time.deltaTime * 5;`